# Compiling 32-bit Node.js on a 64-bit device

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get a 32-bit Node.js executable build on a 64-bit device.

I also asked on Node.js' GitHub page, but I couldn't solve the problem: *[Error During Node Build Process #48583](https://github.com/orgs/nodejs/discussions/48583)*

The error I got during the process:

```
Return code is -31
make[1]: *** [tools/v8_gypfiles/generate_bytecode_builtins_list.target.mk:13: /workspace/node/out/Release/obj/gen/generate-bytecode-output-root/builtins-generated/bytecodes-builtins-list.h] Error 225
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm a665f57085c97becc8e697d5d0d22eab075bd2c3.intermediate 7cfab85011f54b205c49d612bad76cc42e87be84.intermediate
make: *** [Makefile:113: node] Error 2
```

The code I use:

```
sudo apt install -y gcc-multilib \
  g++-multilib \
  ccache \
  crossbuild-essential-i386 \
  lib32z1-dev

sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm

./configure --without-intl \
  --without-dtrace \
  --without-etw \
  --without-npm \
  --without-corepack \
  --without-node-snapshot \
  --without-inspector \
  --without-ssl \
  --shared \
  --shared-zlib \
  --cross-compiling \
  --dest-os linux \
  --dest-cpu x86

export CC="ccache gcc"
export CXX="ccache g++"
export CXXFLAGS="-m32 -Os"
export CFLAGS="-m32 -Os"

make -j$(nproc)
```

Comment: Does [that missing backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594949/compiling-32-bit-node-on-64-bit-device/76595171#comment135053239_76595171) make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Unfortunately the problem persists. I think I skipped copy/paste, normally backslash was there.